# Automate Quickbook Desktop functions

Tags: quickbooks

I was wondering if the Quickbooks Desktop API allows developers to automate some functions.

First, I'm interested in getting the data from the P.O Number, Via, and Account# boxes. Second, I want to perform actions like Ship via UPS, without having to click any of the buttons on the form.

This is very specific for one company and how they fill out their Invoices. Any advice would be a big help!

Comment: I advise contacting them. I did once and got a lot of help automating some features. Not the exact end point, but this is where your tour begins: https://developer.intuit.com/

Comment: Thanks Kai Qing, I submitted a Support Incident ticket. I will post my findings if I can for others who want to do the same.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they may not have directly resolved my issue, but referred me to someone that did. I did have to write the code though, but he pretty much walked me through the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPP Intuit Anywhere is the new platform only for SaaS applications.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#What_types_of_applications_are_supported_with_QuickBooks_API.3F

Dev docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

QBD API docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows

Intuit still provides the traditional **QBSDK SDK** v12, which is useful if you are creating a **custom integration for one company**, or focused entirely on desktop scenarios only.

QBSDK Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Thanks

Comment: I've done some looking around on the QBSDK reference, but I've started to loop back on myself in terms of what I want to do. I don't know if this might help, but the invoiceMod sample code is extremely close to what I would like to do: [link](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#InvoiceMod(VB)(qbfc)(desktop))

However, I'm curious if I can integrate my application into the create Invoice window then just pull the information straight from the GUI controls.

Comment: Alright, I've done some work and have come to a good stopping point. I ended up using both the SDK as Manas Mukherjee mentioned and Win32api to get closer to finishing my project. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Best Wishes.
Thanks